# liquibase scripts over mysql image running in docker from maven for integration tests

Tags: java, mysql, maven, docker, liquibase

As title says I'm trying to find a way to run liquibase scripts that we have over fresh mysql docker image from maven to run integration tests against.

So far I only have found maven plugin to pull and run my docker container and I managed to pull liquibase xmls and sqls from the other project that I need, into the current one.

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <useColor>true</useColor>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <removeVolumes>true</removeVolumes>
                <images>
                    <image>
                        <name>mysql:5.7.9</name>
                        <run>
                            <env>
                                <MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>${mypassword}</MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>
                            </env>
                            <ports>
                                <port>3306:3306</port>
                            </ports>
                            <volumes>
                                <bind>
                                    <volume>
                                        ${project.build.testOutputDirectory}/db-scripts:/tmp/import:ro
                                    </volume>
                                </bind>
                            </volumes>
                        </run>
                    </image>
                </images>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>start</id>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>start</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>stop</id>
                    <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>stop</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

But I'm still struggling to find a way on how to apply all of this scripts on the database that I run in docker before all the integration tests.

Could someone please shed some light on this matter. Thanks

UPD: found liquibase maven plugin, but still facing an issue of liquibase updating schema in mysql docker image. Having an error:

```
Error setting up or running Liquibase: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

my settings for liquibase plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <changeLogFile>${path_to_changelog}/changelog.xml</changeLogFile>
                <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
                <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306</url>
                <username>${mysql_username}</username>
                <password>${mysql_password}</password>
                <promptOnNonLocalDatabase>false</promptOnNonLocalDatabase>
                <logging>debug</logging>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>update</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Hello, have you found a solution for this ? Thanks

Comment: I think the solution will be to have the liquibase put in another container that will startup right after the mysql container.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of docker-maven-plugin this can be fixed using rule to wait on a port like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
    <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.25.1</version>
    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
        <dockerHost>http://10.10.121.137:2376</dockerHost>
        <images>
            <image>
                <alias>docker-mvn-test</alias>
                <name>mysql:5.7</name>
                <run>
                    <wait>
                        <tcp>
                            <host>10.10.121.137</host>
                            <ports>
                                <port>3306</port>
                            </ports>
                        </tcp>
                        <time>20000</time>
                    </wait>
                    <env>
                        <MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>abc123</MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>
                        <MYSQL_DATABASE>testdb</MYSQL_DATABASE>
                        <MYSQL_USER>mysql</MYSQL_USER>
                        <MYSQL_PASSWORD>mysql</MYSQL_PASSWORD>
                        <MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>123456</MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD>
                    </env>
                    <ports>
                        <port>3306:3306</port>
                    </ports>
                </run>
            </image>
        </images>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```